# Two-dimensional data structure of objects

Tags: arrays, r, list, object, data-structures

I would like to store an object in a two-dimensional data structure in R. I have searched and tried several solutions, but none of them do what I want. This is what I had in mind:

```
S = SomeTwoDimensionalStructure(dim=c(2,4))

S[1,1] = LoadDataObject("File1")
s[1,2] = LoadDataObject("File2")
# etc

FunctionWantingObject(S[1,1])
```

[This](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-February/065919.html) solution is quite close, but requires accessing `S[[1,1]]` instead of `S[1,1]`.

Adding the objects to a list and then using `dim` resulted in the later functions not being happy with the argument passed.

Comment: The solution depends in the structure of `LoadDataObject("File1")` object? Can you please, edit your question adding this `str(LoadDataObject("File1"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to give your two dimensional structure a new class, you can then define a special `[` method for it that does what you want.

```
## Make sample data, a matrix of lists, of class "listmatrix"
set.seed(44)
m  <- matrix(lapply(sample(9), function(X) sample(letters, size=X)), ncol=3)
class(m) <- "listmatrix"

## Define a new `[` method for "listmatrix" objects
`[.listmatrix` <- function(x,i,j,...) `[[`(x,i,j,...)

## Check that it works
m[1,2]
# [1] "m" "f" "h" "y" "r" "x" "q" "k" "n"
```

Comment: That's in effect similar to requiring the extra structure in `S[[1,1]]`? Is there anything "wrong" with having to use `S[[1,1]]` instead of `S[1,1]`?

Comment: Doesn't seem the same to me. You only type the `[[` once, in the definition of the method. After that, to retrieve the contents of any of the matrix elements (rather than a length one-list wrapping the contents), you just use, e.g. `S[1,1]`, which is what it sounded like you were asking for.

Comment: Ok, yes. I meant it's the same in principle in that the `[` method replaces typing the `[[`.

Comment: Gotcha. Yep, it's the same, as you can confirm by trying `identical(m[[1,2]], m[1,2])` for any `"listmatrix"` `m`. If, for some reason, you want the results you would have gotten from the "generic" version of `[`, just do something like `list(m[1,2])`. And finally, no, there's nothing wrong with having to use `S[[1,1]]`. It's what I'd use myself, since I and other R users have come to expect that `[` returns a trimmed down version of the original object, whereas `[[` returns the contents of one of that object's elements. Takes a while to grock, but it's an often useful distinction.